# Why Salesforce Partner User's Role Shows an Id instead of the account name?

Tags: community, user-management, admin, partner-portal, digital-experience

When I created the user, the Role was displaying the Parnert Account's name + the role hierarchy, but now it shows the account ID

Does anyone know how to change it back to show the account name instead, like  -- ***Acme Partner Executive***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior where the role shows the ID instead of the Name is part of the consideration when enabling Platform Encryption, account name in role shows as ID is because the account name is encrypted.

> If you encrypt the Account Name field and do not use personal
> accounts, the encryption affects how user roles are displayed to root
> users. Normally, the site user's role name is displayed as a
> combination of their account and user profile names. When you encrypt
> the Account name field, the account ID is displayed instead of the
> account name.
>
> For example, when the Account Name field is not encrypted, users of
> the Customer User profile belonging to the Acme account would have the
> roleAcme Client User. When the Account name field is encrypted (and
> personal accounts are not used), the role could be e.g001D000000IRt53
> client user.

Review considerations on [Shield Platform Encryption](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_considerations_general.htm&type=5) and [Encrypting Experience Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_encryption.htm&type=5).